# ShowDialog() Not showing the form on top of the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a winforms application that handle's subscription data. The main form checks if the user is in the datastore(xml file) if not i call this. UserDetails is a data entry form.

```
else
{
    Form frm = new UserDetails();
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

The Problem is the UserDetail form is not on top and I can select the main form.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on this code.  When it hits, use Debug + Windows + Threads.  Ensure it runs on the main thread.

Comment: Can you post a small program that duplicates this issue? Everything I've tried works as expected.

Comment: What does your method that your code snippit came from look like, seeing the entire method might help

Answer (score 12):

This may happen if your main form is `TopMost`.

Try using

```
frm.ShowDialog(this);
```

when called from the main form.

This will ensure that the dialog is a visual child of the main form, and even if the main form is `TopMost`, the dialog will be above it.

Comment: Calling `fmr.ShowDialog()` from a `TopMost = true` form still puts the dialog on top of the TopMost form. So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @Rotem Thank You I tried frm.ShowDialog(this); but it's the same result. I am beginning to wonder if this is a vs2012 bug.

Comment: @Frazzle - Check which one of the forms is causing the problem: Try launching the dialog from a new default form, and conversely, try launching a default dialog from your main form.

Comment: @JonB I'll leave this here until the correct answer is found to avoid others posting it.

Comment: @Frazzle might consider editing the question to indicate he already tried this (it was the first thing I thought of, too!)

Comment: You made my day! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of the bellow solutions:

1. try to use **Show** method with topmost property set to true:

```
frm.TopMost = true;
frm.Show(mainForm);
```

2. try to use **ShowDialog** method:

```
frm.ShowDialog(mainForm);
```

using from one of the above solutions depends to your UI and logic.